How to make the ZSH suggestions better
Consider, the ZSH suggestions. It is based on most recent commands, which makes what I am about to say logical but also frustrating to work with.
Say I have a folder app with two sub-folders - app-backend and app-frontend.
Let's type out some commands:
cd ./app/app-frontend
cd ../app-backend

Based on these two commands, wouldn't it be only logical that the next time I type cd ../ I should see app-frontend as a suggestion? I am already in app-backend, why does ZSH suggest cd ../app-backend? I understand, it is the last location I typed out from when I was in app-frontend but who thought that this is a good idea - to suggest cd back in the same location where I already am?
How do I solve this horrible thing?

the suggestion is based on command history ... you are looking for some version of command auto-complete instead
